# Best practice to maintain a user id (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I use FormsAuthentication, but I've added a custom MemberShipProvider to validate against a custom User Table.

All tables containing "user data" have a idUser column, so I need to maintain the user id in order to present the user with his data.

Previously I've used a session variable (ASP.NET Webform), but as I am rewriting the webapplication to MVC, I'd like to ask what is generally considered as the best approach for this.

Is session variable still the best place to hold the idUser, or should I add a custom "Current.User.Identity" which in addition to username also holds a public userId ??

Or should I choose a completly different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question when I implemented a custom membership provider for MVC. I ended up doing two things. I store the user's Id in the `ProviderUserKey` field of the `MembershipUser` object. See [provideruserkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.provideruserkey.aspx). Then to answer your question, yes I created a custom principal from System.Web.Security.IPrincipal, though I later inherited from `System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal` instead since I wanted support for Roles.

```
public class MyPrincipal : RolePrincipal
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public MyPrincipal(string providerName, IIdentity identity, Guid id) : base(identity)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

**Update:** The reason I didn't want to use session in my case is because I've disabled it for the app. I've read that the core concept behind MVC is that separation of concerns, and that is closely models the way the web works, which is stateless. Though I can't remember where I read that now that I try to remember. However I do remember also reading that if you can eliminate the session you should do so. It will allow IIS to serve up simultaneous requests from your app rather than having to wait for one request to finish (and release the user's session) before the next request can use the session and send it's response. The biggest impact of which is loading page content using Ajax.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of a similar approach. Though I do agree with @Mark S. above, that the simplest thing is to use the session object.

Comment: Added details for why I avoided the session

Comment: Session isn't necessarily evil and can be a necessity. Often I see users disable session and begin to rely too heavily on cookies increasing the size of every HTTP request. Another way to serve simultaneous requests is to use Asynchronous Controllers which is pretty easy in the MVC4 beta and can be done with a little work in previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

Are your usernames unique? If so there's no need to maintain the UserId as you can simply retrieve a user by username.

My MVC projects have implemented Membership in much the same was as a traditional Web Forms application. I don't think there is any reason to look at the two differently unless you're trying to build a stateless REST type application. How did you maintain your UserId in Web Forms? Session? Then use session in MVC. There's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Of course if you have other reasons for changing there are a lot of way to store the UserId. You could store it in the UserData of the authentication cookie. You could also create your own Authentication ticket that uses the UserId as a key rather than the username. You could even create a Custom Principal to store some additional information.

You may want to review [Forms Authentication Configuration and Advanced Topics](http:////http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs) . This article covers storing additional data (UserId) in the authentication ticket and creating a Custom Principal. Both methods would likely fit your requirements.

Comment: The usernames are unique, but I need the userId cause that's the identity column in my model (database). So get data from a table I need to query it with ... where userid = idUser. I'll look into the link you provided :)

Comment: Session is the easiest, and quickest way to maintain your UserId. The use of MVC certainly doesn't preclude the use of session. My 2 cents, use session.

Comment: I agree. It's doing fine in my webform application. My main concern was that in MVC that approach was "out-of-date".  Thanks again! :)