# What is the approach to use user id's throughout my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database-design

Related content is here: [Best practice to maintain a user id (MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675471/best-practice-to-maintain-a-user-id-mvc)

The authentication service, provided through IdentityDbContext, is ideal for my web application. I am able to add fields I want each user to have and everything is packaged nicely (so I don't have to make big changes to authentication). Included in this package of goods is a ApplicationUser_Id that sits in the AspNetUsers. My question is should I be using the ApplicationUser_Id as my user id throughout the application, **or** should I populate a separate, non-Identity table to hold my user id?

I would love if someone with a similar situation can explain their thought process of choosing one or the other (or a completely different usage!)

---

**EDIT**

As request, I need to transition from my WebForms application to MVC (for scalability reasons). Previously in my WebForms application, I had a database with many tables. A majority of these tables were joint tables in which I used userId as a foreign key. In my previous application, I stored user information in a table called `Users`, and subsequent data was stored in `UserHasMonitor`, `UserHasKeyboard`, `UserHasCPU`, etc. I also had tables as `Monitor`, `Keyboard` and `CPU`.

My WebForms application was to keep record of users and the parts of a computer that they owned. Each entity, such as a monitor or keyboard, was saved in its own table. Tables were joined together with joint tables and the data was displayed by querying the joint tables.

Since moving to MVC, I want to take advantage of the built in authentication that comes with the Identity provided by MVC. With this I get a unique userId and password hash and other fields that I find I will need. However, because this is a new ballgame, my question is how should I be using my user id now that it is within the Identity provider, rather than a custom `Users` table like I had before?

I have it set up now, my MVC application, with 2 connection strings. One connection string handles all Identity tablework while my other connection string will hold my joint tables.

So, to boil it down:

1. How do I integrate a user id with an MVC application that also uses many joint tables? Separate connection strings? Two separate databases?
2. Should I be using virtual to connect my tables together (within my models) now that I am using Identity tables; will this alter the way my joint tables look?
3. Any code examples are always nice, I've looked around but haven't found a good-defined procedure to use, so that is why my question is here.

Comment: You haven't told us what you want to use the user id _for_.

Comment: I will clarify the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except that it looks a bit weird, I do no see a problem to use that ID in the application, it is still the primary key of the user.

If you do not like that kind of ID, then a separate table would be a disastrous idea, instead you can make ASP.NET Identity use Integers as primary keys, check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/798001/ASP-NET-Identity-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Usi), it may also help you understand how Identity works and how you can extend it.

==========

**EDIT**

Since I cannot comment under your post, I hope you see this.

> How do I integrate a user id with an MVC application that also uses many joint tables? Separate connection strings? Two separate databases?

The answer is a single connection string, single database and a context, inheriting NOT from DbContext, but from IdentityDbContext. For example(assuming you're using code-first migrations):

```
public class yourContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    static yourContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<yourContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<yourContext, Configuration>());
    }

    public yourContext()
        : base("Name=YourConnectionString")
    {
    }
}
```

Inheriting from IdentityDbContext will create the db tables needed for Identity to work in you current database.

---

> Should I be using virtual to connect my tables together (within my models) now that I am using Identity tables; will this alter the way my joint tables look?

You should create your table relationships as usual(e.g. Fluent API) in the OnModelCreating method

---

> Any code examples are always nice, I've looked around but haven't
>   found a good-defined procedure to use, so that is why my question is
>   here.

Here is how I connected my Identity user to a contact:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{            
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(c => c.Contact)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ContactId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And in my ApplicationUser class(derived from IdentityUser) I have this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: For reference on how to make a fluent api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx